# distinict pair in julia

Tags: string, dictionary, julia

you wil be given an array integer, and number, you should to return the sum of number in (a,b) example : (1,2,3,6,7,8,9,1) and the number is 10 the output is = (1,9),(2,8),(3,7),(8,2),(9,1),(9,1)

```
    function sumpairs(input, k)

        map = Dict{Int,Int}() 
        count = 0

        for n in input
            complement = k - input[n]
            compl_freq = get(map, complement, 0)

            if compl_freq != 0
                count += 1
                if compl_freq == 1
                    delete!(map, complement)
                else
                    map[complement] -= 1
                end
            else
                map[n] = get(map, n, 0) + 1
            end

        end
          return count
        end
 sumpairs([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2],6)
```

i wrote the code in julia, but it doesn't work, can some one explain why? and if its wrote right ?

Comment: You are missing some of the code. There is no value for `k` and the code must be wrapped inside a `function` declaration. Did you write this yourself? Can you provide the entire code?

Comment: i edit the code, but it still not workimg.. can you tell me why ?

Comment: Now you have `input` and `k` both as input arguments *and* as constants inside the function. And the `return` statement is in the wrong place. Can you try to clean this up, and then post an example showing how you call it and what output you get?

Comment: i edited it , it still with no output and no error

Comment: What do you mean? It *does* return an output. It returns the number `2`. I don't think that's what you want, though. Why are you returning `count` instead of `map`? You need to understand the algorithm if you're going to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumpairs(inputvector::Vector{Int64},k::Int64)
    # first create an empty dictionary
    mydict = Dict{Int64,Int64}()

    # Put the inputvector elements into the mydict
    for n in inputvector
        mydict[n] = 1
    end

    # create an outputvector
    outputvector = Vector{Tuple{Int64,Int64}}(undef,0)

    # Now loop throught the inputvector again
    for number in inputvector
        complement = k - number
        if haskey(mydict,number) && haskey(mydict,complement)
            push!(outputvector,(number,complement))
        end
    end

    # Now return the outputvector
    return outputvector
end

resultvector = sumpairs([1,2,3,6,7,8,9,1],10)
println("RESULT = $resultvector")
println("COUNT = ",length(resultvector))
```

The output of the program is

```
RESULT = Tuple{Int64,Int64}[(1, 9), (2, 8), (3, 7), (7, 3), (8, 2), (9, 1), (1, 9)]
COUNT = 7
```